# BigDecimal causes NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, currency, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

I am working on a financial app and i have to use BigDecimal to calculate currency.Now I am trying to make one entrance activity which is searching in the SharedPreferences for a previous registration and if their is one it starts another activity , if not it starts the registration activity.The problem is the registration activity causes NumberFormatException Error while I am trying to construct a new object of time Profit (the Profit class contains BigDecimal field).Also I am not quite sure that I am using SharedPreferences right.I am not quite sure that my idea and my coding are fine because I am new at android development and i am stuck with this problem so I am giving you all the classes.

the Registration activity:

```
public class Registration extends Activity {

private static String enteredPassword;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    final EditText password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
    final EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    final EditText availability = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.availability);
    EditText profitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profit);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.period_spinner);
    Button registrationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registrationButton);

    DatePicker picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.thePicker);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.periods_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    final String balance =  availability.getText().toString().replace(",",".");
    String profitPeriod = ((Period) spinner.getSelectedItem()).name();
    final Profit profit = new Profit("regular_profit", profitEditText.getText().toString(),
            profitPeriod ,picker);

    registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (password1.getText().toString().equals(password2.getText().toString())) {
                enteredPassword = password1.getText().toString();
                Repository.setPassword(enteredPassword, mContext);
            }
            Repository.setBalance(balance, mContext);
            Repository.setProfit(profit, mContext);
        }
    });

}
```

}

the profit activity

```
public class Profit {



private Date mProfitDate;
private Date mNextProfitDate;
private BigDecimal value;

public final static String TITLE = "title";
public final static String PERIOD = "period";




Profit(String title,String value, String period, DatePicker picker) {
    this.mTitle = title;
    if(value!=null){this.value = new BigDecimal(value);}else{ this.value = new BigDecimal("0.0");};
    this.mPeriod = Period.class.cast(period);
    this.mProfitDate = Repository.getDateFromPicker(picker);
}




public long getNextProfitDate(Date profitDate, Period period){
    long unixProfitDate = profitDate.getTime() / 1000L;
    long nextProfitDate=0;
    switch (period){
        case DAILY:
            nextProfitDate = DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS/1000 + unixProfitDate;
            break;
        case WEEKLY:
            nextProfitDate = DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS/1000 + unixProfitDate;
            break;
        case MONTHLY:
            Date dateNow = new Date();
            dateNow.getTime();
            nextProfitDate = Repository.monthsToSeconds(Calendar.getInstance()
                    .get(Calendar.MONTH)) + unixProfitDate;
            break;
        case YEARLY:
            nextProfitDate = DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS/1000 + unixProfitDate;
            break;
    }
    return nextProfitDate;
}
```

}

the entrance activity

```
public class EnterActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);

    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 100) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
         public void onFinish() {
            if(Repository.getPassword(mContext.getApplicationContext()).equals("No Value")){
                Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(mContext, Registration.class);
                startActivity(registrationIntent);
            }
            else{
                Intent configurationIntent = new Intent(mContext, Configuration.class);
                startActivity(configurationIntent);
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

}

the Repository

```
public class Repository {

public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static String getPassword(Context context){
    return getPrefs(context).getString(PASSWORD,"No Value");
}
public Repository() {
}


public static void setPassword(String password, Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefs(context).edit();
    editor.putString(PASSWORD, password);
    editor.commit();
}
public static void setBalance(String balance, Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefs(context).edit();
    editor.putString(BALANCE, balance);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void setProfit(Profit profit, Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPrefs(context).edit();
    editor.putString(BALANCE, profit.getValue().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

the output

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/.Registration}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:282)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:438)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at .Profit.<init>(Profit.java:41)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at .Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:57)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're going to need you to work on your question a bit more before we can help you. You haven't shown a stack trace, and you've shown *way* more code than I suspect is relevant. Please try to cut it down to a *minimal* example, tell us the values involved, and show the complete stack trace.

Comment: I am really sorry about the lots of code and I will really appreciate your help. I will try to cut the code and edit the post right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate a `Profit` in only one place in the code you presented:

```
Profit profit = new Profit("regular_profit", profitEditText.getText().toString(),
        profitPeriod, picker);
```

If that causes a `NumberFormatException` then it must come from this code in the `Profit` constructor:

```
if(value!=null){this.value = new BigDecimal(value);}else{ this.value = new BigDecimal("0.0");};
```

Since the `value` String will have come from invoking `toString()` on an object, you can rely on it to not be `null` (and anyway, if it were `null` then you would end up at `new BigDecimal("0.0")`, and you can verify for yourself that that works fine).  That leaves us with `new BigDecimal(value)` as the culprit.  [The docs for this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) provide details of the expected format of the argument string.  If the argument does not comply with that format then a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown.

Among the more likely malformed strings that one might imagine in a scenario such as you describe is an empty string, which is not the same as `null` in Java.  Given that the text is coming from a UI field, you also have to watch out for fun and difficult-to-spot malformations such as leading and trailing whitespace.

Perhaps it would be better to write the affected part of the constructior like so:

```
if (value != null) {
    value = value.trim();
    this.value = value.length() == 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : new BigDecimal(value);
} else {
    this.value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Do note that even with that change, this constructor will still throw `NumberFormatException` in the event of other kinds of malformation.  Wherever you are uncertain about the validity of the data, you should be prepared to handle such an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't parsing your string to a Big Decimal correctly.

The following in your `Profit` contructor:

```
if(value!=null)
{
    this.value = new BigDecimal(value);
}
else
{ 
    this.value = new BigDecimal("0.0"); 
}
```

Needs to parse the string to a BigDecimal. Like the following where `this.value` is of type BigDecimal:

```
this.value = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(value);
```

Also keep in mind that `decimalFormat.parse` can throw a `ParseException`. You will need to handle it with try/catch or throw it.

Comment: Sorry, no.  `new BigDecimal(value)` is fine for a `value` whose contents are formatted appropriately.  On the other hand, if `value` is *not* formatted appropriately then `DecimalFormat` provides no help, for it's behavior is itself defined in terms of `BigDecimal(String)` (if it is even configured to return `BigDecimal`s at all, which is not the default).